# What causes the "ConvertResourcesCases" failed unexpectedly?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

did anyone facing this kind of problem too? It happened when I upgrade Xamarin to current version. Already check at xamarin forum, still zero answer. 
Thanks.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2):
>   Error MSB4018: The "ConvertResourcesCases" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml' is denied.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String
>   destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName,
>   Boolean overwrite)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfChanged(String source, String
>   destination)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.FixupResources(ITaskItem
>   item, Dictionary`2 acwMap)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.FixupResources(Dictionary`2
>   acwMap)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()
>   (MSB4018) (Gcm.Client)

Comment: Did you try to delete `obj\Debug\' folder manually?

Comment: yup. still have the same problem.

Comment: What happens when you move your project to another folder?

Answer (score 8):

Delete the contents of obj folder inside project. 
Clean the build. 
Rebuild the project.

Now, everything should work fine. I had this problem once. It is due to the conflict in files that are created when you build the project

Comment: Not here! Doesn't compile the first time.

Comment: I'm getting this error more often than not when I compile these days. It's getting really annoying. Is there anywhere I can report it so someone will fix this?